# Exec format error while executing the file in embedded device from telnet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uclinux

I have an embedded device which consist of 32-bit ARM-7 Winbond CPU and uClinux OS. I have Windows 7 64-bit machine. I have install Virtual Box for Ubuntu for compiling the program as well as uploading it through ftp server. the file in embedded device is being executed from telnet server. The device has its own vdi file but its unable to open the image in virtual box so I install Ubuntu in Virtual Box.

The problems are:

1. When I compile a program and upload in the device through ftp, while executing the file from telnet its does not execute the program and shows "Exec format error".
   So i debugged the executable file it shows "***stack smashing detected***".
   How to solve this?
2. When I copy the sample code from windows to Ubuntu from server in virtual machine and loaded the program in device through ftp is not executed. And the same I did with windows 7, i uploaded the sample code in device through windows ftp the program is being executed. 
   Why does this happens?

Comment: How you compiled this program? You need to compile it specially for this device.

Comment: I compiled the program in Ubuntu using Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a program that is built for different architecture.
Your app is built for x86 64-bit architecture, and you try to run it on 32-bit ARM)
You have to cross-compile your program for given architecture.

Here you can read about cross compilation:

- http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler
- http://www.torriefamily.org/~torriem/wiki/computer_stuff:crosscompiler